# how to pass the control to another web application and get back the response in my asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In my asp.net application, i have one login page.When user pressing the submit button after filling username and password, i have to pass this login credentials to external web application's page.That external application will process the information and response whether it is a valid user or not.

for example : i have to pass the information to the external application in following format

```
http://sampleUrl/login.php?username=alex&password=123
```

and the response from the application is Login Success

So, in my page, i have to process the response to know about valid user or not?...

As far as i know, Response.Redirect("url"); It will completely transfer the control to another page...

Comment: use webservice and pass the credential(uid=alex&pass=123) which return boolen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine for me...

```
 try
            {
                string username = "eval1";
                string password = "dsfdf@";

                // Prepare web request...  
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://someurl/login.php?username="+username+"&password="+password);
                myRequest.Method = "GET";
                myRequest.ContentType = "application/text";

                System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwresponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                if (hwresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    System.IO.Stream responseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream();
                    System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
                    responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString().Trim();                   
                }
                hwresponse.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        Response.writeln("error message:"+e1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply redirect to your home page with flags for decide whether Valid or invalid user.

Like,

```
http://sampleUrl/Home.php?Valid=1
```

In the Home page you can check whether it is valid.
If the flag is not valid You can simply redirect to the login page.

:)

Comment: The external web page is not visible to user...my whole process after pressing submit button will happen on server side only...

Answer (score 0):

In your page

sampleUrl/login.php?username=alex&password=123

add the logic that if login is successfull it will redirect with querystring set to 1 and if unsuccessfull it will redirect with querysreing set to 0

pharse the querystring and apply you successfull logic when querystring is set to 1 and unsuccessfull logic when querystring is set to 0.

if making changes to login.php is beyond your scope you can try webresponse and see what it comes for the two login events.. i think it will be different for each case so you can apply your logic here also.